# tracMe() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pError' File "E:\Desktop\drone test\drone testing.py", line 63 tracMe(info,pid,pError)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tello-drone

There is problem with this tello code don't know how to solve it can any one tell how to fix this?i am getting the track back error

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre]. you have given an incomplete traceback and no code at all to match it.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 arguments instead of 4 arguments.

```
def tracMe(info,w,pid,pError):
```

In line 63 should be like this:

```
tracMe(info,w,pid,pError)
```